# Intermittent EADDRINUSE :::5000

Tags: node.js, express, io-socket

So, sometimes when I reboot my server it fixes it and sometimes it doesn't but I continuously get `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5000`. In my `package.json` in my client I have a proxy for `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` and I changed that to port 3000 to test it, still issue persisted. I went into `server.js` and tried just changing the port but any port I change it to it says it's in use. So, it has to be an issue with how I am setting up express i'm assuming. I just don't know what to even change since it's intermittent.

Also it's weird my server is still running because my socket works...

edit
Here are my scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
  },
```

**server.js snippet**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var server = app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
);
var io = (module.exports.io = require("socket.io").listen(server));
```

Comment: Can you run netstat or similar tool to identify the process that is binding to the port? I assume that if it occurs after reboot that the problem is either caused externally or at startup, not during teardown/exit of your app.

Comment: What commands do you use to to run the server?

Comment: `"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",` And then I just run npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using  `killall node` if I ran into this issue